# Can HTTPS POST data be read by third parties?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rest, security

If I log a user in via a secure HTTPS AJAX POST, does this mean the body of the HTTP POST is encrypted and therefore secure?

Comment: Yes, if the body with the information is visible to the hacker then yes he can steal the users information

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki Your response is kind of redundant... I'm asking if the https (Secure SSL) will protect the HTTP requests body.

Comment: https is just a protocol for transferring your data from users machine to server in a secure fashion(with encryption). If you are showing any information in the browser then its open to all and any one can write a script to get the information.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki Well, I'm not necessarily showing this information in the browser. When the user logs in, the AJAX script will send their username and password to the server. I will be sending the username and password to the server within the body of that encrypted HTTP request.

Comment: I am not understanding this part "within the body of that encrypted HTTP request.". You must be sending data via ajax that is the only way to send information.

Comment: The AJAX is sending an HTTP request to the API which is then analyzing the request, can any of the data be read by anyone besides the user currently using the browser?

Comment: If that is the case then you are secured, no one else can read that information unless the other person gets access to current logged in users system.

Comment: Answering the question "can any of the data be read by anyone besides the user currently using the browser", this is not true. For example any admin on the client can read the data, as well as any admin on the server, or anybody that can access the user running the webserver (not necessarily an admin). See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to protect against (what threats should be mitigated).

HTTPS is a secure channel between the client (browser in this case) and the server. This means anybody with sufficient privileges on the client, and also on the server can read the data, because those are the ends of the imaginary pipe that HTTPS is. Practically any admin on the client or on the server can read the transmitted data, but a man-in-the-middle attacker (somebody on the network inbetween) cannot, HTTPS is secure against that (and only that, albeit it's not just confidentiality that HTTPS provides, but that's a separate topic).

The more important question is, how will you put the username and password into the body of an ajax request? That would mean you had to store such username and password somewhere on the client, where it is most probably not very secure. For instance any single successful XSS attack can reveal such credentials to an attacker. That would probably be my primary concern in this case.

Comment: I edited my question, but your answer still makes sense enlight of what I was asking. I've recently learned a few things on the subject and worded it correctly.